# How to change background color of elements in ListView(data from ContentProvider)?

Tags: android, listview, android-contentprovider

I need to change the background color of elements in ListView depends on their status.
lvLinks.getCount() returns the correct value. "If-else" and logs works correctly also. But it doesn't work (doesn't change color of background). Please, help me! Hope you will understand my code.

```
final Uri CONTACT_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.application.provider.LinkProvider/links");
ListView lvLinks;
Cursor cursor;
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.history);

    lvLinks = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvLinks);
    showListView(null);
    setBackgroundColor();
    lvLinks.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}


public void showListView(String order){
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(CONTACT_URI, null, null,
            null, order);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    int to[] = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };
    String from[] = {"ref" , "status"};
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cursor, from, to);
    lvLinks.setAdapter(adapter);


}

public void setBackgroundColor(){


    for(int i = 0; i < lvLinks.getCount(); i++){
        View v = lvLinks.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) lvLinks.getItemAtPosition(i);
        int status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("status"));
        Log.d("MYTAG", String.valueOf(status));
        if (status == 1){
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            Log.d("MYTAG", "GREEN");
        } else if (status == 2){
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            Log.d("MYTAG", "RED");
        } else if (status == 3){
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            Log.d("MYTAG", "GRAY");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Your adapter should be handling setting the backgroud color of the view when you bind the contact data to that row. `SimpleCursorAdapter` has no logic to do this. You should extend `CursorAdapter` and implement `bindView()` to handle this the way you want.

Second: `startManagingCursor()` is deprecated. Learn to use the `Loader` framework, specifically `CursorLoader`.